# Relocating electrical conduit for new door

Tags: electrical, doors, pvc

I need to install a new door in this location and I am partly there but I am unsure of the proper way of moving this PVC conduit closer to the top junction box seen in the photo. Should I cut at the top left corner, pull and start over or is there an easier way here? Besides a heat gun is there any easier way of dealing with this? Any suggestions appreciated!

Thank you! [image]

Comment: Should we assume an access panel is unacceptable?

Answer (score 2):

There's no real easy way to move that junction box. Basically, you need to remove all the wires going into that box. Then get rid of the double 90 bend to the left, shorten the conduit going to the top box and re route the conduit to the right to  move the box up to where you need it to be. Re route the left section to the new box location. Then re pull the wires into the newly located box. You shoudn't need to pull new wire.

You could also possibily replace the top junction box with a much larger one and route your conduits into the new box and totally eliminate the box in question.

Save the heat gun for shrink tubes.